# using JSON ValueObject vs MySQL rows

Tags: php, mysql, json, laravel, value-objects

Hey guys I'm having a dilemma with devising some logic for a Laravel application I'm developing and could use some advice.

I have Eloquent Models A and B that needs arbitrary meta data. This meta data would not be updated frequently but may however change in properties/ characteristics and I might want it "searchable"( To be decided). would it be better to store the meta data as an eloquent model table as key/value row

e.g. pseudo table

```
-----------------------
|Key|Value|Relation ID|
-----------------------
```

Or store as a serialized ValueObject/ JSON

e.g. pseudo table

```
------------------
|Relation ID|JSON|
------------------
```

Please note that I would be using PRE 5.7 so using JSON column types in MySQL is a no go!

Comment: The first option is going to be best for MySQL in my opinion.  Your data will be normalized and thus easier to search/query.

Comment: 'key' and 'value is a reserved word in MySQL and should be avoided. A better naming and structure would be: id, meta_key, meta_value.

Comment: @DanielO. pseudo columns

Comment: maybe you can use cache since the meta data will be changing. Depending on the size of that meta data and the form i.e is it dynamic, or is it like a configuration data that is shared...

Comment: I use option 2 a lot with models and it works well. If you override the accessors and mutators, it becomes even easier and you wouldn't need the JSON column type, I use Aurora which doesn't have JSON types so I just use longText. Let me know if you want a little more info about how I do it.